# Zybooks Python Challenge Activity

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to complete this challenge activity in Zybooks for python but I feel it must be missing some critical information for me to actually complete it. Here is the question.

> 350 square feet requires 1 gallon of paint. Assign gallons_paint with the amount of paint required for wall_area.

Sample output for the given program:

```
250.0 square feet wall will need:
0.714285714286 gallons of paint
```

Here is the template code given. I cant modify lines 1-2 and the last 2 lines, only between.

```
wall_area = 250.0
gallons_paint = 0.0

''' Your solution goes here '''

print(wall_area, 'square feet wall will need:')
print(gallons_paint, 'gallons of paint')
```

so I simply just did `gallons_paint = 250 / 350`

That apparently passes test 1 but fails in test two which is just states this...

```
Testing with wall_area 578.6
Your output
0.7142857142857143
Expected output
1.6531428571428572
```

But if I change `gallons_paint = 578.6 / 350` or add an additional line states `gallons_paint = 578.6 /350` and run the checker, I then fail test 1 and it never gets to test two.  This is only Chapter 2 so we haven't even started doing if and else statements or anything complicated.

Anyone know what I was supposed to do?

Comment: Please clarify your question and share the code you've used so far

Answer (score 0):

Your clue is how you calculated the `gallons_paint`. 
You declared `gallons_paint = 250 / 350`, but it never said that "250" was the number it was going to use. 'calculate using variables' and not values by 'the coder'. 

To put it another way, mathematically we know that an area of a rectangle is Length * Width = Area (lw = A). We (the coder) are to substitute the values in, and then calculate. Given a 2 by 3 rectangle, we can say "2x3 = 6". But that is not true for ALL rectangles. 
We can think:

- L = 2, W = 3
- substitute values into the formula
- lw = A -> (2)(3) = A
- (2)(3) = A -> 6 = A

The formula is "wall_area / gallons_paint_per_sf = gallons_paint"
when coding "gallons_paint = 250/350" for the single case of "wall_area = 250", this is true, but not for any "wall_area".

```
gallons_per_sf = 350
gallons_paint = wall_area/gallons_per_sf
#or gallons_paint = wall_area/350
```

The difference is is that we never declare the value of ANYTHING besides gallons_per_sf. This is static, unchanging, like pi for circle area and perimeter.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:-**

```
def paintneed(n):
  paint = 1
  sqfeet = 350
  print ("{} square feet wall will need".format(n))
  print ("{} gallons of paint".format((paint/sqfeet)*n))

paintneed(250) #your output
```

Answer (score -1):

*"Finish the program to compute how many gallons of paint are needed to cover the given square feet of walls. **Assume 1 gallon can cover 350.0** square feet. So gallons = the square feet divided by 350.0. If the input is 250.0, the output should be:"*

I got stuck on this one too. You have to define for the program, what the gallons per square feet are AND also the calculation for figuring out how many gallons you'll need for a room.  I ran it using the value 350 and then with the variable, both passed tests.

> gallons_sqft=350.0 
>   gallons_paint=wall_area/350.0
>
> OR
>
> gallons_sqft=350.0
>   gallons_paint=wall_area/gallons_sqft